# How to use Monad Transformers to combine different (both pure and impure) monads?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

I'm writing my first Haskell application, and I'm having a hard time understanding the use of Monad transformers.

Example code:

```
-- Creates a new user in the system and encrypts their password
userSignup :: Connection -> User -> IO ()
userSignup conn user = do
    -- Get the encrypted password for the user
    encrypted <- encryptPassword $ password user.     -- encryptPassword :: Text -> IO (Maybe Text)
    -- Updates the password to the encrypted password
    -- if encryption was successful
    let newUser = encrypted >>= (\x -> Just user { password = x })
    -- Inserts the user using helper function and gets the result
    result <- insertUser (createUser conn) newUser
    return result
    where
        insertUser :: (User -> IO ()) -> (Maybe User) -> IO ()
        insertUser insertable inuser = case inuser of
            Just u -> insertable u -- Insert if encryption was successful
            Nothing -> putStrLn "Failed to create user" -- Printing to get IO () in failure case
```

Problem:

- How to avoid actions like printing to console (as done in `insertUser` helper function), for cases where no output is produced by `IO`. More specifically, how to create a "zero" value for IO monad?
- How to combine two different kind of monads (in this case Maybe and IO) so that I can combine their contents and produce one unified result that may contain either the result, or the possible error?
- How to express such a problem in a functional way that's more understandable?

Comment: As written, your question is rather unclear. In general "How can this be improved" is an ambiguous question, and will likely get closed as opinion based (those kinds of questions are typically for the code review SE). What is the "unintended case"? What isn't working as you expect?

Comment: `result <- ...; return result` is equivalent to not binding result at all; Regarding your question about code review - there exists a separate se-site exactly for that purpose - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - I would propose migrating this question

Comment: You can create a `m ()` value for any `Monad m` (including `IO`) with `return ()`

Comment: Thanks all for suggestions. I do feel that this is a question for StackOverflow and not a code review request. I'll edit my question text to clarify that and make it more obvious. Sorry for not being clear about this in the first attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edit:* updated answer to match your updated question.

Just to be clear, you aren't actually *using* any monad transformers in your code example.  You're just nesting one monad inside another.  For an example using a real monad transformer `MonadT`, see my answer to your second question.

**For your first question,** as @David Young commented, you can use `return ()`:

```
showSuccess :: Bool -> IO ()
showSuccess success =
   if success then putStrLn "I am great!"
              else return ()    -- fail silently
```

More generally, if a function returns `IO a` for some type `a`, then you can always return a "pure" value that has no associated IO action by using the `return` function.  (That's what `return` is for!)  In the case of a function returning `IO ()`, the only value of type `()` is the value `()`, so your only choice is `return ()`.  For `IO a` for some other type `a`, you'll need to `return` some value of type `a`.  If you want the *option* to return a value or not, you'll need to make the type `IO (Maybe a)` or use a `MaybeT` transformer, as below.

**For your second question,** you're basically asking how to neatly express nested computations in the `Maybe` monad:

```
let newUser = encrypted >>= (\x -> Just user { password = x })
```

within an outer `IO` monad.

In general, extensive computations in nested monads are painful to write and lead to ugly, unclear code.  That's why monad transformers were invented.  They allow you to take facilities borrowed from multiple monads and bundle them up in a *single* monad.  Then, all bind (`>>=`) and `return` operations, and all do-syntax can refer to operations in the same, single monad, so you aren't shifting between "IO mode" and "Maybe mode" when you're reading and writing code.

Rewriting your code to use a transformer involves importing the `MaybeT` transformer from the `transformers` package and defining your own monad.  You can call it anything you like, though you'll likely be typing it a lot, so I usually use something short, like `M`.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

-- M is the IO monad supplemented with Maybe functionality
type M = MaybeT IO
nothing :: M a
nothing = mzero  -- nicer name for failing in M monad
```

Then, you can rewrite your `userSignUp` function as follows:

```
userSignUp :: Connection -> User -> M ()
userSignUp conn user = do
  encrypted <- encryptPassword (password user)     -- encrypted  :: String
  let newUser = user { password = encrypted }      -- newUser    :: User
  insertUser <- createUser conn                    -- insertUser :: User -> M ()
  insertUser newUser
```

I've added some type annotations in the comments.  Note that the new `M` monad takes care of ensuring that each variable bound by the `<-` operator will have already been checked for `Nothing`.  If any step returns `Nothing`, processing will be aborted.  If a step returns `Just x`, the `x` will be automatically unwrapped.  You don't typically have to deal with (or even see) the `Nothing`s or `Just`s.

Your other functions must live in the `M` monad, too, and they can either return a value (success) or indicate failure like so:

```
encryptPassword :: String -> M String
encryptPassword pwd = do
  epwd <- liftIO $ do putStrLn "Dear System Operator,"
                      putStrLn $ "Plaintext password was " ++ pwd
                      putStr $ "Please manually calculate encrypted version: "
                      getLine
  if epwd == "I don't know" then nothing   -- return failure
    else return epwd                       -- return success
```

Note that they can use `liftIO` to lift operations to the underlying IO monad, so all IO operations are available.  Otherwise, they can either return pure values (via `return`) or signal failure in the `MaybeT` layer with `nothing` (my alias for `mzero`).

The only thing left now is to provide a facility to "run" your custom monad (which involves converting it from an `M a` to an `IO a`, so you could actually run it from `main`).  For this monad, the definition is trivial, but it's good practice to define a function in case your `M` monad is more complicated:

```
runM :: M a -> IO (Maybe a)
runM = runMaybeT
```

A complete whole working example with stub code is included below.

**For your third question,** making it "more functional" won't necessarily make it more understandable, but the idea would be to make use of monad operators like `=<<` or applicative operators like `<*>` to mimic a functional form in a monadic context.  The following would be an equivalent "more functional" form of my monad transformer version of `userSignUp`.  It's not clear that this is more understandable than the imperative, "do-notation" version above, and it's certainly harder to write.

```
moreFunctionalUserSignUp :: Connection -> User -> M ()
moreFunctionalUserSignUp conn user
  = join $ createUser conn
           <*> (setPassword user <$> encryptPassword (password user))
  where
    setPassword u p = u { password = p }
```

You can imagine this as roughly equivalent to the pure functional computation:

```
  createUser conn (setPassword user (encryptPassword (password user)))
```

but with the right operators sprinkled in to make it type-check as a monadic computation.  (Why do you need `join`?  Don't even ask.)

### Full MaybeT Example

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

-- M is the IO monad supplemented with Maybe functionality
type M = MaybeT IO
nothing :: M a
nothing = mzero  -- nicer name for failing in M monad

runM :: M a -> IO (Maybe a)
runM = runMaybeT

data User = User { username :: String, password :: String } deriving (Show)
data Connection = Connection

userSignUp :: Connection -> User -> M ()
userSignUp conn user = do
  encrypted <- encryptPassword (password user)     -- encrypted  :: String
  let newUser = user { password = encrypted }      -- newUser    :: User
  insertUser <- createUser conn                    -- insertUser :: User -> M ()
  insertUser newUser

encryptPassword :: String -> M String
encryptPassword pwd = do
  epwd <- liftIO $ do putStrLn "Dear System Operator,"
                      putStrLn $ "Plaintext password was " ++ pwd
                      putStr $ "Please manually calculate encrypted version: "
                      getLine
  if epwd == "I don't know" then nothing   -- return failure
    else return epwd                       -- return success

createUser :: Connection -> M (User -> M ())
createUser conn = do
  -- some fake storage
  return (\user -> liftIO $ putStrLn $ "stored user record " ++ show user)

main :: IO ()
main = do username  <- putStr "Username: " >> getLine
          password  <- putStr "Password: " >> getLine

          let user = User username password
          result <- runM (userSignUp Connection user)

          case result of
            Nothing -> putStrLn "Something failed -- with MaybeT, we can't tell what."
            Just () -> putStrLn "Success!"
```

Comment: Also, I should mention, most people prefer alternatives to `MaybeT` that allow returning an explanation of what went wrong, i.e., an error message, whether it's a plain string or a structured exception.  Some people use `ExceptT` (formerly `ErrorT`) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Yes, I realise that I wasn't using any monad transformers, that's what I wanted to use though. I didn't really know that this is what a monad transformer is. Your made that clear for me in your answer.

Comment: I have one more quick question about your answer. The `M ()` output in the `userSignup` function is what is called a Free Monad, right? Since it's not really a computation, but a set of computations that can be run?